# using structure result in one file into another file?

Tags: c

I have two files: p1.c and p2.c.

I need to use the value stored in the structure in p1.c into p2.c. Please help me figure out how to achieve this. Should I use `extern`?

p1.c

```
typedef struct What_if
{
    char price[2];
} what_if ;

int main()
{
    what_if  what_if_var[100];

    file * infile;
    infile=fopen("filepath");

    format_input_records();
}

int format_input_records()
{
    if ( infile != NULL )
    {
        char mem_buf [500];

        while ( fgets ( mem_buf, sizeof mem_buf, infile ) != NULL ) 
        {
            item = strtok(mem_buf,delims);     
            strcpy(what_if_var[line_count].price,item) ;
            printf("\ntrans_Indicator     ==== : : %s",what_if_var[0].price);
        }
    }
}
```

p2.c

```
"what_if.h"  // here i include the structure

int main()

{
    process_input_records(what_if_var);
}

int process_input_records(what_if *what_if_var)
{
    printf("\nfund_price process_input_records    ==== : : %s",what_if_var[0]->price);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i need to read the value from the file and store it in a structure in p1.c.. then i want this result structure from p1.c in another files like p2.c and p3.c etc

Comment: Hmmm ... do you want to be able to save the p1.c result values "somewhere", and afterwards (next week) use them in p2.c? Or do you prefer p1.c to get results and instantly make them available to p2.c without the need to save them? If it's the 2nd option, you don't want 2 `main`s; you want to compile and link all of the p1.c, p2.c, p3.c, ... together.

Comment: yup, i prefer p1.c to get results and instantly make them available to p2.c without the need to save them,. ok i don't need two main .plz help me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

whatif.h:

```
#ifndef H_WHATIF_INCLUDED
#define H_WHATIF_INCLUDED

struct whatif {
    char price[2];
};
int wi_process(struct whatif *);

#endif
```

p1.c

```
#include "whatif.h"

int main(void) {
    struct whatif whatif[100];
    whatif[0].price[0] = 0;
    whatif[0].price[1] = 1;
    whatif[1].price[0] = 42;
    whatif[1].price[1] = 74;
    whatif[99].price[0] = 99;
    whatif[99].price[1] = 100;
    wi_process(whatif);
    return 0;
}
```

p2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "whatif.h"

int wi_process(struct whatif *arr) {
    printf("%d => %d\n", arr[0].price[0], arr[0].price[1]);
    printf("%d => %d\n", arr[1].price[0], arr[1].price[1]);
    printf("%d => %d\n", arr[99].price[0], arr[99].price[1]);
    return 3;
}
```

Then compile and link all of them together, for example with `gcc`

```
gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall p1.c p2.c
```